# Combine 2 unknown distributions in r

Tags: r, distribution, normal-distribution

I'm having difficulty to combine (adding or subtracting) 2 different distributions. So I have 2 distributions of microbial level in stage A and stage B. Those are as followed:

```
Stage A <- 0.47787 2.24880 0.60905 2.02392 1.32117 1.08692 0.87141 2.05203 1.54605 0.45913 1.12440 1.13377 1.81778 2.21132 0.83393 0.64653 2.53927 1.16188 2.39872 1.36802 1.90211 1.05881 1.81778 1.49920 1.32117 1.30243 1.30243 1.65849 1.20873 2.52053 2.54864 2.65171 2.20195 1.03070 2.03329 0.74023 0.89015 1.01196 1.02133 1.80841 0.50598 1.48983 0.88078 0.98385 1.20873 1.77093 1.88337 0.84330 1.53668 2.03329 2.41746 0.84330 1.55542 0.90889 1.78030 2.14573 2.30502 1.04007 1.63975 0.32795 1.50857 1.35865 2.28628 1.47109 1.91148 0.62779 0.76834 2.36124 0.47787 1.24621 0.96511 1.08692 1.83652 1.99581 0.98385 1.42424 1.12440 0.91826 1.48046 1.13377 1.23684 0.78708 1.63975 0.89015 0.53409 1.27432 2.52053 0.95574 1.55542 1.16188 1.16188 0.73086 0.94637 0.91826 2.27691 1.23684 2.02392 0.84330 1.19936 1.70534 1.04007 1.08692 0.74023 1.24621 0.47787 1.49920 1.98644 1.13377 2.84848 2.52053 0.97448 0.53409 1.98644 0.89015 2.38935 1.45235 1.69597 2.51116 1.18062 1.67723 2.04266 1.39613 1.38676 1.70534 2.35187 2.00518 1.73345 1.31180 1.04007 0.70275 1.51794 1.94896 1.10566 0.41228 0.88078 1.76156 1.06818 1.72408 1.93959 2.37998 1.59290 0.57157 1.72408 1.42424 0.81519 0.39354 2.29565 2.52990 1.46172 1.01196 2.02392 0.39354 2.05203 1.02133 1.62101 0.84330 1.53668 2.34250 1.97707 1.22747 0.86204 1.82715 1.66786 1.32117 2.23943 0.40291 0.37480 2.05203 1.93022 0.97448 1.76156 0.88078 1.83652 0.67464 1.82715 1.38676 1.69597 1.35865 0.60905 0.84330 2.13636 2.31439 1.04007 1.18999 2.01455 1.39613 1.77093 2.22069 1.55542 2.55801 0.92763 0.97448 2.23006 1.13377 0.66527 1.41487 1.67723 1.10566 3.03588 1.19936 1.33054 1.21810 1.37739 1.95833 1.79904 1.01196 1.17125 2.51116 0.54346 0.78708 0.66527 2.53927 1.15251 1.63038 1.72408 2.83911 1.31180 0.98385 1.37739 0.93700 0.81519 2.78289 1.68660 0.68401 1.00259 1.93959 1.05881 0.76834 0.43102 2.55801 1.83652 1.60227 1.04944 1.06818 2.17384 1.16188 1.92085 1.05881 2.09888 1.73345 1.10566 0.68401 0.59031 1.53668 2.38935 2.18321 0.77771 1.72408 1.11503 4.43201 1.05881 0.83393 1.25558 0.77771 2.60486 2.30502 1.31180 1.04944 0.88078 1.29306 1.86463 2.16447 2.50179 2.61423 0.91826 0.77771 0.97448 2.40809 1.81778 0.96511 1.52731 1.60227 0.89015 1.65849 0.73086 1.08692 1.24621 1.89274 0.81519 1.70534 2.37998 0.22488 1.83652 0.32795 1.22747 0.75897 2.82037 2.26754 0.68401 0.80582 1.68660 1.72408 1.37739 1.37739 2.23006 2.17384 2.72667 1.63975 2.41746 0.47787 0.62779 1.38676 0.40291 2.44557 1.63975 0.82456 2.69856 0.62779 1.30243 0.38417 1.82715 1.15251 2.04266 1.77093 1.48046 1.28369 2.40809 1.26495 1.86463 2.30502 0.67464 1.29306 1.02133 1.60227 1.17125 2.02392 1.52731 0.97448 1.89274 0.27173 1.21810 0.75897 0.45913 1.42424 2.12699 1.20873 2.38935 0.63716 1.42424 0.74960 0.53409 2.66108 1.80841 0.80582 1.07755 1.84589 2.91407 0.53409 0.67464 0.82456 1.94896 0.94637 1.59290 0.92763 1.47109 1.73345 1.51794 1.92085 1.11503 1.86463 0.53409 1.70534 2.11762 0.66527 1.21810 1.32117 1.47109 1.91148 0.66527 1.48983 0.29047 1.05881 2.50179 1.30243 2.37998 1.54605 0.14055 1.98644 1.07755 1.86463 2.39872 0.47787 1.03070 0.79645 1.85526 1.25558 1.26495 1.60227 0.96511 1.56479 1.67723 2.01455 1.23684 2.43620 0.61842 0.31858 1.59290 2.39872 2.33313 1.28369 1.03070 1.24621 1.93022 1.13377 0.90889 2.46431 1.61164 0.89015 2.03329 2.58612 0.36543 1.97707 2.29565 2.13636 1.40550 2.23006 1.61164 0.52472 1.68660 1.34928 1.48983 1.04944 2.10825 0.71212 1.86463 1.83652 0.86204 1.84589 1.91148 1.56479 2.57675 0.94637 1.91148 2.40809 2.00518 2.56738 0.60905 0.98385 1.05881 0.67464 1.51794 1.87400 1.09629 0.71212 1.20873 2.80163 1.49920 0.88078 1.25558 2.33313 0.83393 1.12440 1.70534 2.24880 2.73604 2.58612 1.44298 1.37739 0.88078 1.38676 0.94637 1.12440 0.81519 1.12440 1.22747 0.79645 1.69597 0.59968 0.68401 1.76156 2.24880 1.68660 1.54605 2.18321 2.21132 0.93700 2.70793 1.77093 0.77771 2.08014 1.12440 1.58353 2.54864 1.27432 2.15510 1.94896 2.80163 1.57416 0.77771 0.53409 2.03329 2.50179 0.65590 0.77771 1.35865 1.54605 1.77093 1.70534 1.95833 1.66786
Stage B <- 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03863988 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03222680 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03477759 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03250592 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03858306 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

Those data is usually presented by log10 value. It can be seen that almost all of value in Stage B are almost zero. So I have to scenarios that came into my mind.

1. My understanding is it would be easier to fit those distributions into normal distribution (using fitdist) and combine them together to get summation of those distributions. However, fitdist to normal distribution will have negative values which is unrealistic in my case.
2. The thought that I have is to fit with lognormal distribution and add them together. However, since I have many zeros in Stage B, I cannot do it as lognormal doesn't allow zero values.

I'm stucked now with those 2 scenarios and have been searching for answer that best solve my problem.

Thank you very much for helping me out of this problem.

best,

Comment: Stage B looks like all 0, so that will have a uniform distribution. Adding these vectors is just a mater of `Stage A + Stage B`. Your script is not correct either need to concatenate with `c` and have commas `,` separating each element eg `StageB=c(0,0,0)`

Comment: Which distribution to fit is a choice that you need to make and justify based on some solid expectation for the sampling distribution of the quantity of interest--not sheer convenience of getting fitdist to work.  You are already doing this by noticing that a normal distribution (which yields negative values) is unrealistic.  I encourage you to continue thinking along these lines: what was the sampling process, and what sort of distribution do you expect to arise from it?

Comment: @JustGettinStarted thanks for the feedback. Sorry, I put it wrongly in my question. Those in the question are vectors already. I should have put only ":" instead of "<-" sign to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JacobSocolar thanks Jacobs. I have two candidates of distribution which are negative binomial distribution and poisson lognormal distribution. These two distribution are normally used for microorganism. With negative binomial, it produces an error "the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100" and I don't know the reason behind that error. WIth Poisson lognormal, I cannot find a a way to coding it in R. 

My final aim is to merge 2 distributions. But I dont know how to do it. I can  do it when the distributions are both normal.

Comment: @qillbel  What did the sampling process that yields this distribution look like?  Where do the data come from?  Why does stage B have so many zeros?  These are the key questions that are prerequisite for thinking about which statistical distributions might have given rise to these data.

Comment: @JacobSocolar thank you for replying Jacob. The data is about the growth of bacteria. Stage A is an initial level of bacteria, and stage B is the level of bacteria after the food is cooked. Stage B has so many zeros, because once the food is cooked properly, then all bacteria is death Otherwise, there are some bacteria left depending on time and temperature. 
By random chance, it happens that food is cooked properly most of the time, and that's why Stage B has so many zeros. 
I hope I explained it better.

Comment: It sounds to me like distribution B then is thresholded--you get some distribution of bacteria up until the point where the food is cooked enough, and then you get zero.  Abundances are often log-normal in distribution.  Therefore, the distribution I would suggest would be a zero-inflated lognormal.  So this would be a 3-parameter distribution.  The first would control the probability that the abundance is zero or not.  And the second two would be the ordinary log-normal parameters to model the abundance given that it is non-zero.

Comment: Another way to say it--decompose the abundance distribution into two parts: one part that just says "is it zero or not" and a second part that treats the non-zero values as arising from a lognormal.